# Scala: Concatonate two instances of Option[List]

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following:

```
val l1 = Some(List(1))
val l2 = Some(List(2))
```

I would like to concatenating `l1` and `l2` so that I get a `List(1, 2)` or `Nil` if both Options are equal to `None`.

I'm happy to use scalaz if there is an elegant solution there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l1.getOrElse(Nil) ::: l2.getOrElse(Nil)`

Answer (score 3):

There's also this option:

```
List(l1, l2).flatMap(_.toList).flatten
```

Which can easily be used for any number of `Option[List[_]]` values

Answer (score 1):

using [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) library is much more simpler when you use the [semigroup](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/semigroup.html) type class

```
import cats._ , cats.implicits._ , cats.instances._ 

scala> Option(List(3)) |+| Option(List(5))
res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(3, 5))

scala> Option(List(3)) |+| None
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(3))
```